# How do I run a callback in a specific window from an event handler?

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

I've got a SwiftUI window which I'd like to show/hide while some keys are pressed. I've got a switch based on appstorage:

```swift
struct FooApp: App {
    @Environment(\.scenePhase) private var scenePhase
    @AppStorage("hotkeyHeld") var hotkeyHeld: Bool = false
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            if hotkeyHeld {
                ContentView()
            } else {
                EmptyView()
            }
        }
        .onChange(of: scenePhase, perform: { newScenePhase in
            if newScenePhase == .active {
                Hotkeys.register(
                    funcPressed: { hotkeyHeld=true },
                    funcReleased: { hotkeyHeld=false })
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Unfortunately in the usual `InstallEventHandler` callback implementation, I cannot directly call the `funcPressed`, `funcReleased` functions because:

```
A C function pointer cannot be formed from a closure that captures context
```

so a callback like this is not possible:

```swift
InstallEventHandler(GetApplicationEventTarget(), {
  (nextHanlder, theEvent, userData) -> OSStatus in
      funcReleased()        
      return noErr
}, 1, &eventType, nil, nil)
```

How can I work around this and execute those functions on the right thread?

Comment: What is `Hotkeys.register`? That is not a part of SwiftUI as far as I know.

Comment: @Sweeper Just a wrapper around the Install/Register calls for the event handler - all the boilerplate not really relevant here, I added the `InstallEventHandler` call to the snippet to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite a full solution, but using the [HotKey library](https://github.com/soffes/HotKey) solved my immediate problem. Setting a callback as:

```
hotkey.keyDownHandler = { ... }
```

does not have the same restrictions.